# Mongo find query only returns one result

Tags: mongodb

Hello I have the following data structure :

```
[
  {
    "name": "a name",
    "project": [
      {
        companyName: "a name",
        contactPerson: [
          {
            work_email: "test@test.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        companyName: "a name1",
        contactPerson: [
          {
            work_email: "test1@test.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        companyName: "a name2",
        contactPerson: [
          {
            work_email: "test2@test.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        companyName: "a name3",
        contactPerson: [
          {
            work_email: "test@test.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      
    ]
  }
]
```

With this query i want to find all projects that have the email test@test.com :

```
db.collection.find({
  "project.contactPerson.work_email": "test@test.com"
},
{
  "project.$": 1
})
```

It only returns the first result it finds and then it just stops. but in my data i have two projects with that email and i want to find both. here's a playground you can use to further help me if you can. Thanks in advance and much appreciated : https://mongoplayground.net/p/4Mpp7kHi98u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positional $ operator limits the contents of an  to return either:

1. The first element that matches the query condition on the array.
2. The first element if no query condition is specified for the array
   (Starting in MongoDB 4.4). [Ref](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

You can do something like following,

```
[
  {
    "$unwind": "$project"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "project.contactPerson": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$project.contactPerson",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.work_email",
              "test@test.com"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          "$project.contactPerson",
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      project: {
        "$addToSet": "$project"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qgWhBC2-H01)

Comment: You can simplify slightly and eliminate the unwind and group stages by filtering `$project`  using [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html#in-aggregation) like `cond: {$in: ["test@test.com","$$this.contactPerson.work_emai"]}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$project"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "project.contactPerson.work_email": "test@test.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "name": {
        "$first": "$name"
      },
      "project": {
        "$push": {
          "companyName": "$project.companyName",
          "contactPersion": "$project.contactPerson"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

//step1(problem statement related find):, find shows all projects even one of the array element of contact is matched, use an aggregate function to display specific email ids

```
> db.test3.find({    "project.contact.email": "abc2@email.com" }).pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f43fdc153e34ac6967fe8ce"),
        "name" : "Pega Contractors",
        "project" : [
                {
                        "pname" : "pname1",
                        "contact" : [
                                {
                                        "email" : "xyz1@email.com"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "pname" : "pname2",
                        "contact" : [
                                {
                                        "email" : "abc2@email.com"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "pname" : "pname3",
                        "contact" : [
                                {
                                        "email" : "xyz1@email.com"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
--
//aggregate option:

//Step1: data preparation
> db.test3.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f43fdc153e34ac6967fe8ce"),
        "name" : "Pega Contractors",
        "project" : [
                {
                        "pname" : "pname1",
                        "contact" : [
                                {
                                        "email" : "xyz1@email.com"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "pname" : "pname2",
                        "contact" : [
                                {
                                        "email" : "abc2@email.com"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "pname" : "pname3",
                        "contact" : [
                                {
                                        "email" : "xyz1@email.com"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
>

//step2: aggregate and unwind project for the next step pipeline input
> db.test3.aggregate([ {$unwind: "$project"}]);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f43fdc153e34ac6967fe8ce"), "name" : "Pega Contractors", "project" : { "pname" : "pname1", "contact" : [ { "email" : "xyz1@email.com" } ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f43fdc153e34ac6967fe8ce"), "name" : "Pega Contractors", "project" : { "pname" : "pname2", "contact" : [ { "email" : "abc2@email.com" } ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f43fdc153e34ac6967fe8ce"), "name" : "Pega Contractors", "project" : { "pname" : "pname3", "contact" : [ { "email" : "xyz1@email.com" } ] } }

//step3: Desired outcome, i.e display data specific to email
> db.test3.aggregate([
...    {$unwind: "$project"},
...    {$match: {"project.contact.email":"xyz1@email.com"}}
...    ]);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f43fdc153e34ac6967fe8ce"), "name" : "Pega Contractors", "project" : { "pname" : "pname1", "contact" : [ { "email" : "xyz1@email.com" } ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f43fdc153e34ac6967fe8ce"), "name" : "Pega Contractors", "project" : { "pname" : "pname3", "contact" : [ { "email" : "xyz1@email.com" } ] } }
> db.test3.aggregate([    {$unwind: "$project"},    {$match: {"project.contact.email":"acb2@email.com"}}    ]);
> db.test3.aggregate([    {$unwind: "$project"},    {$match: {"project.contact.email":"abc2@email.com"}}    ]);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f43fdc153e34ac6967fe8ce"), "name" : "Pega Contractors", "project" : { "pname" : "pname2", "contact" : [ { "email" : "abc2@email.com" } ] } }
>
```